# Getting random 404 requests from unknown IPs in Apache + Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, http, apache2, digital-ocean, csf

This is strange.

I just installed a new Ubuntu + Apache in my Digitalocean droplet and installed a Laravel APP there.

Now suddenly I see these kind of strange POST, GET and CONNECT requests from unknown IPs.

[Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ErW.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ErW.png)

How can I prevent these kind of requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They are the backgrounds noise of being connected to the internet.

It's a tangle of compromised machines scanning for vulnerable targets to compromise, security researchers looking for something, tools such as shodan.io scanning, spammers looking for comment sections to spam and so forth. It's not a single source, and it is simply background noise at this point.

What you *should* do:

1. Ensure you're using up to date software.
2. Know your software and it's behaviour.
3. Read logs. Look for unknown activity.
4. Potentially put a Web Application Firewall in front of the application, to limit what kind of requests actually hits the application. This can mitigate a lot of security vulnerabilities if configured correctly.